# PXSelector attribute suppress Error on form

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I have created a custom Location field for warehouse locations:

```
    #region UsrTOLocation
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "To Location")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<
        INLocation.locationCD,
        Where<INLocation.siteID, Equal<Current<INRegister.toSiteID>>>>))]

    public virtual string UsrTOLocation { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTOLocation : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrTOLocation> { }
    #endregion
```

When the location does not exist I create it using code in a button.
Since I have added the PXSelector to the above field I keep getting an error when it doesn't find the locations. This is correct because I still need to create it

Is there a way to suppress the error that it is not finding the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ValidateValue property of the PXSelector attribute.

For instance:

```
    [PXSelector(..., ValidateValue = false)]
```

It disables validation and therefore error appearing in PXSelector attribute